# Unexpected result when copying an array in Java

Tags: java

How am I getting output 123346 for the below program:
Where does 5 go?

```
public class TestClass {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] scores = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
         System.arraycopy(scores, 2, scores, 3, 2);
         for(int i :  scores)
             System.out.print(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: You copy 3 and 4 over 4 and 5 in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.arraycopy(scores, 2, scores, 3, 2);
```

This copies 2 items from source index 2. therefore {3, 4} into destination position 3. Since your source and destination arrays are the same you're overwriting the 5 with the 4

```
          {3  4}      <== items copied
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}   <== original

  0  1  2  3  4  5    <== indexes

{ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6}   <== output, the 4 has overwritten the 5, damn
```

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite the `5` (and the `4` as well, technically). See the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)).

The source and destination objects are the same, and your `length` parameter is `2`, while the indices are different, thus, *two* numbers at each index will be copied to those positions.

Source numbers and positions:

`1 2 [3 4] 5 6`

Destination positions:

`1 2 3 [4 5] 6`

Result:

`1 2 3 [3 4] 6`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very useful piece of code, but what you are doing is copying 2 element from your source array starting at index 2 to your array starting with index 3.

In effect you arrive with:
1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6

System.arraycopy copies elements from source array to destination array. The method signature is:
`arraycopy(sourceArray, sourceIndex, destinationArray, destinationIndex, howManyElementsToCopy)`.

What you do is specify your array both as source and destination. Therefore your code starts to copy elements from your source array (firs parameter - scores) to your destination array (third parameter - scores). It copies over 2 elements (the last method parameter - 2). It starts to copy elements from source array at index 2 (2nd parameter in method) to destination array starting with index 3 (4th parameter).

Visualised:

```
INDEX:        0  1  2  3  4  5
                    3, 4        <- values that are copied (2 elements from index 2)
source:      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                       4, 5     <- those valuse are overwriten (2 elements from index 3)
destination: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] <- in your case the same array as source                           
                       3, 4     <- values from source copied into destination
result:      [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Actually, it's from the source array at index 2, to the array at index 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method signature for arrayCopy from javadoc:
public static void arraycopy(Object src,
             int srcPos,
             Object dest,
             int destPos,
             int length)

In your call: arrayCopy(scores, 2, scores, 3, 2); the second argument is the source position from where to begin the copy (which is 2 and indexing '3' in your array).

Array index: 0 1 **2** 3 4 5
  score       1 2 **3** 4 5 6

Similarly the forth argument is the destination position (which is 3 and indexing '4' in your array:

Array index: 0 1 2 **3** 4 5
score       1 2 3 **4** 5 6

Finally the last argument is the length of string to copy (which is 2), so 3 and 4 are copied at position 3 to give the output

Array index 0 1 2 **3** 4 5
score       1 2 3 **3** **4** 6